# Give a pre-defined 2-D char array values

Tags: c++, arrays

The char array is defined inside a structure as shown here:

```
struct munchkin_grid_type
{
     char grid[5][5];
};
```

Inside another function, a variable is defined as this new type, and I want the char array inside it filled:

```
munchkin_grid_type munchkin_grid;

munchkin_grid.grid[5][5] = 
{
        { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
        { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' }
};
```

The errors I get are:

- error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'char'
- IntelliSense: too many initializer values

How do I put these values inside this 2-D array without resorting to the std::array/vector types? I just want a normal 2D character array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
munchkin_grid_type munchkin_grid;

munchkin_grid.grid[5][5] = 
{
    { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
    { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' }
};
```

do

```
munchkin_grid_type munchkin_grid = 
{
    {
       { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
       { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
       { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
       { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
       { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' }
    }
};
```

EDIT - as asked to explain the basis of this.

Essentially, this is a definition of a single `struct named`munchkin_grid` with an initialiser.  To understand it, work out from the braces.

A single array of char would be initialised something like

```
char x[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
```

A two dimensional array of char introduces another nesting of `{}`.

```
char x[2][5] = {
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}
  };
```

I've changed the first dimension from your example, since with a 5x5 it is less clear which way the dimension run for initialisation.   If the dimension are swapped, the initialiser also needs to change, for example;

```
char y[5][2] = {
     {'a', 'b'},
     {'c', 'd'},
     {'e', '1'},
     {'2', '3'},
     {'4', '5'}
  };
```

Then the initialisation of a struct adds another level of `{}` to get the initialiser for `munchkin_grid` as above.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Could you explain why that works?

Comment: Yeah, okay, I'll edit shortly with a brief explanation.  A bit too long to put in comments.

Answer (score -1):

The code `munchkin_grid.grid[5][5] =` is accessing an element of an array (you may be confusing syntax with another language...) deleting the `[5][5]` should fix your problem.

EDIT: the following code should work (at least it hasn't produced any IntelliSense errors..)

```
#include <array>
struct munchkin_grid_type
{
    std::array<char, 5> grid[5];
};

munchkin_grid_type munchkin_grid;

munchkin_grid.grid[0] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
munchkin_grid.grid[1] = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
munchkin_grid.grid[2] = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
munchkin_grid.grid[3] = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
munchkin_grid.grid[4] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

Comment: No, it won't fix the problem. You can't initialize (using initializer list) an already declared array.

Comment: @DimChtz how about now?

Comment: @DimChtz It compiles without error using MSVC++ 2015